# Effective data-structure for maintaining state information of multiple servers

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, server, state

I have a small-project which requires me to have a state knowledge of all the servers active in the project.

ANALOGY :- As soon as a pair leaves the table in hotels, the new ones are always ready to occupy those.

But, my case is somewhat different. I want to keep track of all the servers which are active. Say, if Server A, B , C, ... , Z are all active and are responding to a central server. Now, say, if C, P, X and Z have lost their power and are switched off, then my data-structure should store A,B,D,.,O,Q,...,W,Y. And, again if those threaded-servers area restored in alive state, then it'd be easy to put those servers in the way they are coming to life,i.e, they are being restored.

So, in which data-structure (Java) should I keep this record so that the insertion and removal of periodic-status is easy, and the complexity is as least as possible. Also, if a Library/class of Java(Oracle) is referred, it'd be most welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) would work fine for this assuming the ordering of your servers does not matter. Want to see if a server is online? `Set.contains()` Want to add a server that is coming online? `Set.add()` Want to remove a server that is offline? `Set.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an array, give every server a unique ID from 0 to count - 1

```
int NUM_OF_SERVERS = 32;
Server[] servers = new Server[NUM_OF_SERVERS];
...
// server alive
servers[aliveServer.Id] = aliveServer;
...
// server dead
servers[deadServer.Id] = null;
...
// modify server
servers[serverId].property = something;
```